# What does following notations of "approximately equal" mean in paper?

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis

I am reading paper: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/PL00008774. But I meet some notations of "approximately equal" which I feel very confused.

Ex 1: On page 18,
$$
\mathcal{L(\theta)}\sim_{\theta \to \infty} b_1\theta^{-q}e^{\lambda^*\theta}
$$

What does $\sim _{\theta \to \infty}$ mean here? Does it mean $\lim_{\theta\to \infty}\mathcal{L(\theta)}/b_1\theta^{-q}e^{\lambda^*\theta}=1$?

Ex 2: On page 18, Proposition 3.2, what does mean $\textbf{K(t,s)}\approx$?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\mathcal{L(\theta)}\sim_{\theta \to \infty} b_1\theta^{-q}e^{\lambda^*\theta}
$$
Is an asymptotic approximation for $\theta\to\infty$. Specifically, it means
$$
\lim_{\theta\to\infty}\frac{\mathcal{L(\theta)}}{b_1\theta^{-q}e^{\lambda^*\theta}}=1.
$$
In contrast, the symbol $\approx$ has no technical meaning.

Answer (score 0):

It means "is distributed as... or has the distribution function of... in the limit of $\theta$ approaching infinity".

Comment: There are two notations asked about, so "it" is unclear.